How to itemise with a loop for a given variable with ; as delimiters
Problem:
I'm trying to write a function where it can iterate through a variable with ; delimiters to print them as a list.
What I have tried:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\newcommand{\accountnos}{BSB: 012345 Account No.: 123456789; BSB: 054321 Account No.: 987654321}

\newcommand{\printaslist}[1]
{
  \def\do##1{##1, }
  \expandafter\forcsvlist\expandafter{\do}{#1}
  \unskip
}

\begin{document}


I have the following accounts: \printaslist{\accountnos}

\end{document}

Current Output:

Desired Output:

Question:
How can I write a function where the variable \accountnos{} can be printed as \items?  Also, if my approach is incorrect, please feel free to use another approach or package.

It is easier to use expl3. For example, the following implements a slightly different syntax than the one you proposed.

\storelist[<delimiter>]{<name>}{<list>} where <delimiter> defaults to ; and <name> is a name for your list.
\printaslist{<name>} then prints the list as a series of \items in an itemize environment.

It would also be possible (and probably a good idea) to generalise \printaslist to offer more flexibility, but that's all I did for now.
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728139/
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_kstc_acnos_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kstc_printaslist:N
{
  \begin{itemize}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn #1
    {
      \item ##1
    }
  \end{itemize}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \kstc_printaslist:N { c }
\NewDocumentCommand \storelist { O{;} m  +m }
{
  \seq_if_exist:cF { l_kstc_#2_seq } { \seq_new:c { l_kstc_#2_seq } }
  \seq_set_split:cnn { l_kstc_#2_seq } { #1 } { #3 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \printaslist { m }
{
  \kstc_printaslist:c { l_kstc_#1_seq }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { c }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\storelist{accountnos}{BSB: 012345 Account No.: 123456789; BSB: 054321 Account No.: 987654321}

\begin{document}

I have the following accounts: \printaslist{accountnos}

\end{document}


I'd use a different way of storing the list, but here's how you can do, similarly to cfr's suggestion:
\definelist{accounts}{
  BSB: 012345 Account No.: 123456789;
  BSB: 054321 Account No.: 987654321
}

The code below also allows you to use a traling separator, just in case. See the examples.
The \outputlist takes four arguments (list name, pre code, template, post code), the second and fourth being optional. It has a *-variant where the template argument is replaced by tokens that should be inserted between items (so no #1).
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definelist}{mO{;}m}
 {% #1 = list name; #2 = input separator; #3 = list
  \ekstc_list_define:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\outputlist}{smO{}mO{}}
 {% #2 = list name; #3 = pre code; #4 = template; #5 = post code
  \IfBooleanTF {#1}
   {% *-version, with \seq_use:cn
    \ekstc_list_use:nnnn {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5}
   }
   {% normal version, with \seq_map_function:cN
    \ekstc_list_output:nnnn {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5}
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {c}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ekstc_list_define:nnn
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l__ekstc_list_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_split:cnn { l__ekstc_list_#1_seq } {#2} {#3}
  %% in case there's a trailing separator
  \tl_if_blank:eT { \seq_item:cn { l__ekstc_list_#1_seq } {-1} }
   {% remove last item
    \seq_pop_right:cN { l__ekstc_list_#1_seq } \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ekstc_list_use:nnnn
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__ekstc_list_use:n {#3}
  #2 % pre code
  \seq_use:cn { l__ekstc_list_#1_seq } {#3}
  #4 % post code
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ekstc_list_output:nnnn
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__ekstc_list_use:n {#3}
  #2 % pre code
  \seq_map_function:cN { l__ekstc_list_#1_seq } \__ekstc_list_use:n % items
  #4 % post code
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definelist{accounts}{
  BSB: 012345 Account No.: 123456789;
  BSB: 054321 Account No.: 987654321
}

\definelist{test}[,]{
  aaaa, bbb, ccc,
  dd, ee,
}

\begin{document}

\outputlist{accounts}[\begin{itemize}]{\item #1}[\end{itemize}]

\outputlist{accounts}
  [\begin{tabular}{ll}]
  {\textbullet & #1 \\}
  [\end{tabular}]

\outputlist{test}[\begin{enumerate}]{\item \textbf{#1}}[\end{enumerate}]

\outputlist*{test}[List: ]{ -- }[.]

\end{document}



It is easier not to use expl3. For example, the following implements your task directly without need any special macro package.
\documentclass{article}

\def\printaslist#1{\begin{itemize}\expandafter\printaslistA#1;;\end{itemize}}
\def\printaslistA#1;{\ifx;#1;\else \item #1 \expandafter\printaslistA\fi}

\def\accountnos{BSB: 012345 Account No.: 123456789; BSB: 054321 Account No.: 987654321}

\begin{document}

I have the following accounts: \printaslist{\accountnos}

\end{document}


I didn't use 'any special macro package'.
